# Data truncated error on store method with ManyToMany relationships

Tags: laravel, eloquent, many-to-many

I'm new to Laravel and having problems with ManyToMany relationships.

I have two tables:

- members
- groups

A member can belong to many groups, a group can have many members.

I've created the relationships in the models and the pivot table.

When I create a member, I have checkboxes for the groups.

In my store method I do this:

```
....
$member->save();

if(isset($request->groups)) {
 $groups = implode(',', $request->groups);
 $member->groups()->sync([$groups]);
}
```

`dd($groups)` gives: "2,7"

I get the error:

> QueryException in Connection.php line 761: SQLSTATE[01000]: Warning: 1265 Data truncated for column 'group_id' at row 1 (SQL: insert into `group_member` (`group_id`, `member_id`) values (2,7, 5))

Where is this 5 coming from and why do I get this error?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error is because of the data type you entered.

Using

```
implode()
```

You turn the array into a string while sync() method wants an array as input. Let's try just:

```
 $member->save();

 if(isset($request->groups)) {
    $member->groups()->sync($request->groups);
 }
```

Comment: OMG, of course!!! I'm learning laravel for the last few weeks and my head is just too full with information..... Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the inconsistency that might arise due to the comma separated string, I'd convert
`$request->groups`, which is a string, to a standard array before adding it to the sync function.

```
if(isset($request->groups)) {
    $groupIds = array($request->input('groups'));
    $member->groups()->sync($groupdIds);
}
```